# angular regex is not working for 12 digit validation check

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, angular-validation

config.newValue has value as `"888888888888"` and config.regex has value as `"/[0-9]{12}/"`

```
let matches = String(config.newValue).trim().match(config.regex);
```

variable matches should return value as true but it is returning value as null .

Can anyone please help what it is not accepting the correct validation.Validation is only to check that the number is of size 12 and it has digits from 0 to 9 .

Comment: Can anyone please look at this .

Comment: `config.regex="^[0-9]{12}$"`

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues.

1. If you want to check the value length is exactly 12, Your regular expression should be `/^[0-9]{12}$/`.
2. I guess you define `config.regex` with quotation like `const config.regex = "/^[0-9]{12}$/"`. You have to define regular expression variables without quotation like `const config.regex = /^[0-9]{12}$/`;
3. The method `match` returns the matched string. If you just want `true` or `false`, you can use `test` method. `let matches = config.regex.test(String(config.newValue));`.

Comment: i want to get only the matched string . i have config.setRegex('/^\d{12}$/') to insert value in config. regex and for config.newValue ,it is getting whatever value user is entered from UI . I have used  let matches = String(config.newValue).trim().match(config.regex) . But still everytime value is matches is coming as null.

Comment: regex: string;
setRegex(regex) { this.regex = regex; return this; }. This is how i have defined regex and set the value in it.

Comment: (1) You have to define `regex` as `RegExp`. `regex: RegExp; setRegex(regex) { this.regex = regex; return this; }`. (2) you have to call `config.setRegex` without quotation like `config.setRegex(/^\d{12}$/)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal

```js
const config = {
  newValue: "888888888888",
  regex: "^[0-9]{12}$",
}

const allMatches = String(config.newValue).trim().match(config.regex);
const hasMatch = allMatches && allMatches.length > 0;
const fistMatch = hasMatch ? allMatches[0] : undefined;
```

I have created a working example. Click the link and then click [Run] on the right side you'll see console log output results

[Working typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeGBvAUDGYApgO4BqAhgDYCuhAXDAEQAcrb7rjANHjAE6EUhAB4NGAPQDaABgC0ATgC6WAIwAmAL4ASbjg04c8aDCqUAsuSjAAFoQgYYAZSh8kYFAAp4yFADoiZFS0AJS%20LkgAth6hEZY2XuA%20vgJCwsEA3AZGsNbkEBZW1g6mBTZ2MABkFSaU5nG2EL6UhO5QRQB8MNKZ2TDI0KVFmLn59TAA-DV1hXYyijAM1GAAJoTIRMvpMFngECDNTSCeAAYAgrUwsTMQdMdcU4N2GYa7%204SHJwASeZf1DFpYEaDDTHZ5GN4fDzHABiSD4xiuNlBQA)